# wordpress page - positioning elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My wordpress page template is one without columns(left or right sidebar etc.).
When I try to insert two div elements to my page through wordpress rich text editor and style with css it becomes weird:

```
<div id='first'>lalalalala</div>
<div id='second'>lalalalala</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#first{
width:600px;
border-right:1px solid black;
float:left;
}
div#second{
width:200px;
margin-left:10px;
border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

What is werid? div#second is not positioned next to the `#first` one, but instead underneath it.

Parent for both of these is more than 800px in width.

Comment: Can you post the example by chance? It's hard to imagine.

Comment: What is hard to imagine? That I am stuck inside this little **itty thing? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `float:left` for the `div#second` also.

Comment: yes, made it work!! but since when this is the right syntax to use?

Comment: You mentioned width for both the divs. so you need to set float to both of them.